# Как вычислить остаток при делении переменной q на переменную divisor и присвоить результат переменной q?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "Ukr");
    int q;
    int divisor;
    printf("\n Введiть значення q = ", q);
    scanf("%d", &q);
    printf(" Введiть значення divisor = ", divisor);
    scanf("%d", &divisor);

    q = q %= divisor;
    printf("\n q = %d\n", q);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `q %= divisor`?

Comment: %= найти остаток от деления значения переменной на заданное число, результат записать в переменную ?

Comment: @Kodarak Да. Это сокращение для `q = q % divisor;`. Вот только зачем Вы передаете `q` и `divisor` в первые вызовы `printf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправьте `q = q %= divisor;` на `q %= divisor;`

Пояснение: `q %= divisor` тоже самое, что `q = q % divisor`, то есть вы уже присваиваете переменной q остаток при делении q на divisor.

Comment: Можно и не исправлять. `q = q %= divisor;` это масло масляное, то же самое что `q %= divisor; q = q;`

Comment: @avp Верно, просто глаз мозолит)